# AccessError _unknown model

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I am creating a custom module for Odoo 8 which adds custome fields into res.partner. I've been struggling with some troubles with permissions, but when I finally dealed with them I encountered a new error:

[image]

I seems as if it does not recognise my model...

Here you go my code:

**mymodule.py**

```
import openerp
from openerp.osv import fields, osv, orm
from openerp import models

class poligono_poligono(models.Model):
    _name = "poligono.poligono"
    _rec_name= "poligono_name"
    _columns = {
        'poligono_name': fields.char('Polígono', required=True),   
}

class cant_neg_dir(models.Model):  
        _inherit = "res.partner"
        _columns = {
        'dir_poligono_empresa': fields.many2one('poligono_poligono' ,'Polígono'),
}
```

**__openerp__.py**

```
'data': [
        'mymodule.xml',
        'security/mymodule_security.xml',
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    ],
```

**security/ir.model.access.csv**

```
id,name,model_id/id,group_id/id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink 
access_cant_neg_dir,cant_neg_dir.cantnegdir,model_poligono_poligono,cant_neg_dir.group_name_test_user,1,1,1,1
```

**security/mymodule_security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="0">
        <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_name_test">
            <field name="name">Directorio</field> 
            <field name="sequence">7</field>
        </record>
        <record id="group_name_test_user" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Usuario</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_name_test"/>
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
        </record>
        <record id="group_name_test_manager" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Administrador</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_name_test"/>
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_name_test_user'))]"/>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Change your many2one. You are referencing the className not the name attribute of the odoo model.

```
class cant_neg_dir(models.Model):  
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    _columns = {
        'dir_poligono_empresa': fields.many2one('poligono.poligono'     ,'Polígono'),
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! But it turns out that I have no access to those models from other users... It says: AccessError Model: poligon.poligon.

Comment: So you need to find out what security group the users are a part of and ensure the security group has the proper CRUD access to the model.

Comment: Are your users part of the security group you defined? If you look at each user they should have a checkbox or drop down for Directorio and you should select Usuario

Comment: Do you have any logging or errors in your console? Do you have access to the server logs? Have you resolved the issue of the model name previously entered in as 'poligono_poligono'?

Comment: Hello Phillip, I am sorry for the delay. Even if I define users in group I can't access. Only admin user can edit that many2one field.